# Nginx serving wrong site

Tags: nginx, subdomain, php-fpm, domain

I have nginx setup on my vps with a static ip and 2 domains (beryju.org and nope.berlin).

I want to serve:

- Site 1 to beryju.org
- Site 2 to blog.beryju.org
- Site 3 to i.beryju.org
- Site 4 to nope.berlin

Additionally I want beryju.org and blog.beryju.org to support SSL.

But with my current configuration, I am getting:

- Site 1 not at all
- Site 2 on beryju.org and blog.beryju.org
- Site 3 on i.beryju.org
- Site 4 on nope.berlin

I have tried and it also doesn't works when I remove the hostname from the listen statement, i.e.

```
listen i.beryju.org:80;
```

to

```
listen 80;
```

in every file.

## beryjuorg-blog.conf

```
server {
    listen blog.beryju.org:80;
     listen blog.beryju.org:443 ssl;
    ssl_certificate /home/beryju/SSL/nginx/beryju.org.cert;
    ssl_certificate_key /home/beryju/SSL/nginx/beryju.org.key;

    access_log /var/log/nginx/beryjuorg-blog.access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/beryjuorg-blog.error.log;

    root /home/beryju/Apps/Ghost/;
    index index.html index.htm index.php;

    location  / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:2368;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }

}
```

## beryjuorg-image-hoster.conf

```
server {
    listen i.beryju.org:80;

    server_name i.beryju.org;

    access_log /var/log/nginx/beryjuorg-image-hoster.access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/beryjuorg-image-hoster.error.log;

    root /usr/share/nginx/i.beryju.org;
    index index.html index.htm index.php;

    location  /gyazo.php {
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fcgi.conf;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php-fcgi-beryjuorg-image-hoster-php-fcgi-0.sock;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    }


    location  / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }

}
```

## beryjuorg.conf

```
server {
    listen beryju.org:80;
    listen beryju.org:443 ssl;
    ssl_certificate /home/beryju/SSL/nginx/beryju.org.cert;
    ssl_certificate_key /home/beryju/SSL/nginx/beryju.org.key;
    server_name beryju.org;

    access_log /var/log/nginx/beryjuorg.access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/beryjuorg.error.log;

    root /usr/share/nginx/beryju.org/;
    index index.html index.htm index.php;

    location ~ [^/]\.php(/|$) {
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fcgi.conf;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php-fcgi-beryjuorg-php-fcgi-0.sock;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    }

}
```

## nopeberlin.conf

```
server {
    listen nope.berlin:80;

    server_name nope.berlin;

    access_log /var/log/nginx/nopeberlin.access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/nopeberlin.error.log;

    root /usr/share/nginx/nope.berlin/;
    index index.html index.htm index.php;

    location  / {
        autoindex on;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The file `beryjuorg-blog.conf` is missing a `server_name` directive, which means that server block will be a "catch-all" for requests with no HTTP/1.1 Host header (the domain name) or an undefined Host header. See [How nginx processes requests](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/request_processing.html) and [server blocks](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#server) for more on this.

Since you have a static IP address, you can make the configuration more explicit by adding the IP address to the `listen` directive, e.g.

```
listen 192.168.0.3:80;
```

The `listen` directive is not meant to accept a hostname; see [the documentation.](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#listen)

Specifying both `server_name` and an optional IP address for `listen` should resolve the issue.

Comment: Thank you very much; I don't know how I could miss that while trying to fix this.

Comment: @BeryJu, you're quite welcome. I've been in that situation to the point of frustration, and sometimes all it takes to resolve is a fresh pair of eyes.

Comment: `The listen directive is not meant to accept a hostname; see the documentation.`

This is incorrect, see: *Both address and port, or only address or only port can be specified. An address may also be a hostname, for example:*

listen 8000;
listen *:8000;
listen localhost:8000;